# Multiple Laravel 5 projects on the same domain

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

I got several Laravel 5 projects running on subfolders, on the same domain.

Each Laravel application is generating it's own session cookie, and sometimes it generates so much that we get http 400 errors on the entire domain.

Should I share the storage folder between all those projects, or there's any settings to prevent that to happen?

Comment: could you not use just the one then use sub domain routing and use a package systme for each site etc? bit outdated but can give you an idea? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5

Comment: I can't, we really need each project on a subfolder.

Comment: Sorry i read subdomainnot folders? Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I found the solution, let me share with you guys.

First, you need to use a shared session driver like Redis or database.

Second, you need to set on config/session.php, the session cookie and path to be the same.

After that, you can run as many different Laravel projects on the same domain without having problems with cookies.

If your application does not require session at all, you can disable sessions entirelly on app/Http/Kernel.php, commenting the following lines:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Answer (score 6):

Each Laravel installation should be located in its own directory.

Then an alias needs to be defined which points the domain sub-folder to the "child" Laravel folder.

Example in Apache `http.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost some.domain:80>

    ServerName some.domain

    ## Path to laravel domain
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/some/domain/laravel-1/public"
    <Directory "/path/to/some/domain/laravel-1/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ## Path to laravel sub-folder
    Alias /laravel-2-path-alias/ "/path/to/some/domain/laravel-2/public"
    <Directory "/path/to/some/domain/laravel-2/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

For session cookies, check `config\session.php` in both installations.

Root installation `config\session.php`:

```
'cookie' => 'a_unique_name'
'path' => '/',
```

Subfolder installation `config\session.php`:

```
'cookie' => 'another_unique_name'
'path' => '/path/to/sub/folder',
```

This should ensure that each installation is writing its own unique session cookies. Any cookies generated by the sub application should not interfere with those of the parent.

Comment: We already got our projects running, the question is about session cookies.

Comment: Can i share the same session

Answer (score 1):

Edit httpd.conf file as

Please check that path may differ according to your system **/opt/lampp/htdocs/** or **/var/www/html/**

```
## Path to laravel sub-folder
Alias /admin-boilerplate/ "/opt/lampp/htdocs/admin-boilerplate/public/"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/admin-boilerplate/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And you may need to edit .htaccess file in public folder as

```
RewriteBase /admin-boilerplate
```

Full code look like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # It enables routes when documrnt root set to public foder in httpd.conf file
    # change name according to alias name
    RewriteBase /admin-boilerplate
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a unique security key for each sub folder and add a special variable for each sub folder go change the generated cookie

Answer (score 0):

You should setup Homestead. It's super easy to use. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead You can setup multiple domains for example: domain1.dev, domain2.dev. For each domain you'll have your own cookies.

Comment: We are already in production, and we need multiple projects on multiple subfolders.